# Windows Phone - Binding View to View Model

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone

So, I am on my way learning MVVM Pattern for Windows Phone, and stuck how to bind the View to my ViewModel. App that I build now is getting current and next 5 days weather and display it to one of my panorama item on MainPage.xaml using UserControl.

I cannot just simply set the **Forecasts.ItemsSource = forecast;** in my WeatherViewModel, it says that Forecasts (Listbox element name in **WeatherView**) not exist in the current context.

Can anybody teach me how to bind it? and anybody have a good source/example sample to mvvm pattern in windows-phone? Thanks before.

**EDIT:**

**WeatherModel.cs**

```
namespace JendelaBogor.Models
{
    public class WeatherModel
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string ObservationTime { get; set; }
        public string WeatherIconURL { get; set; }
        public string Temperature { get; set; }
        public string TempMaxC { get; set; }
        public string TempMinC { get; set; }
        public string Humidity { get; set; }
        public string WindSpeedKmph { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**WeatherViewModel.cs**

```
namespace JendelaBogor.ViewModels
{
    public class WeatherViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string weatherURL = "http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=";
        private const string City = "Bogor,Indonesia";
        private const string APIKey = "APIKEY";

        private IList<WeatherModel> _forecasts;
        public IList<WeatherModel> Forecasts
        {
            get 
            {
                if (_forecasts == null)
                {
                    _forecasts = new List<WeatherModel>();
                }

                return _forecasts;
            }

            private set
            {
                _forecasts = value;

                if (value != _forecasts)
                {
                    _forecasts = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Forecasts");
                }
            }
        }

        public WeatherViewModel()
        {
            WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri(weatherURL + City + "&num_of_days=5&extra=localObsTime&format=xml&key=" + APIKey, UriKind.Absolute);
            downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(ForecastDownloaded);
            downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
        }

        private void ForecastDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot load Weather Forecast!");
            }

            else
            {
                XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
                var current = from query in document.Descendants("current_condition")
                                     select new WeatherModel
                                     {
                                         ObservationTime = DateTime.Parse((string)query.Element("localObsDateTime")).ToString("HH:mm tt"),
                                         Temperature = (string)query.Element("temp_C"),
                                         WeatherIconURL = (string)query.Element("weatherIconUrl"),
                                         Humidity = (string)query.Element("humidity"),
                                         WindSpeedKmph = (string)query.Element("windspeedKmph")
                                     };             

                this.Forecasts = (from query in document.Descendants("weather")
                                       select new WeatherModel
                                       {
                                           Date = DateTime.Parse((string)query.Element("date")).ToString("dddd"),
                                           TempMaxC = (string)query.Element("tempMaxC"),
                                           TempMinC = (string)query.Element("tempMinC"),
                                           WeatherIconURL = (string)query.Element("weatherIconUrl")
                                       }).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**WeatherView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="JendelaBogor.Views.WeatherView"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:JendelaBogor.ViewModels">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
         <vm:WeatherViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid Margin="0,-10,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="Current" Grid.Row="0" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Column="0" delay:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding WeatherIconURL}" Width="120" Height="120" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Temperature}" FontSize="22"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObservationTime}" FontSize="22"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Humidity}" FontSize="22"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Windspeed}" FontSize="22"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="300"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <StackPanel Height="40" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Date" FontSize="22" Width="170"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="FC" FontSize="22" Width="60"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Max" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="22" Width="90"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Min" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="22" Width="90"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Forecasts}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Height="40" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" FontSize="22" TextAlignment="Left" Width="170" />
                                    <Image delay:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding WeatherIconURL}" Width="40" Height="40" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TempMaxC, StringFormat='\{0\} °C'}" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="22" Width="90" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TempMinC, StringFormat='\{0\} °C'}" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="22" Width="90" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<controls:PanoramaItem x:Name="Weather" Header="weather">
    <views:WeatherView />
</controls:PanoramaItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ViewModel doesn't know about the view.

You need to make a `Forecasts` property on the ViewModel, and bind the ItemsSource to it from your View.  In your view, change the `ListBox` to:

```
<!-- No need for a name - just add the binding -->
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Forecasts}">
```

Then, in your ViewModel, add:

```
// Add a backing field
private IList<WeatherModel> forecasts;

// Add a property implementing INPC
public IList<WeatherModel> Forecasts 
{ 
    get { return forecasts; }
    private set
    {
        forecasts = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Forecasts");
    }
}
```

You can then set this in your method:

```
 this.Forecasts = (from query in document.Descendants("weather")
                             select new WeatherModel
                             {
                                 Date = DateTime.Parse((string)query.Element("date")).ToString("dddd"),
                                 TempMaxC = (string)query.Element("tempMaxC"),
                                 TempMinC = (string)query.Element("tempMinC"),
                                 WeatherIconURL = (string)query.Element("weatherIconUrl")
                             })
                 .ToList(); // Turn this into a List<T>
```

Comment: Bind the element (checked), do the ViewModel (checked, RaisePropertyChanged -> NotifyPropertyChanged), set the method (checked), the data still not appear on the emulator. Am I missing something here? should I post my ViewModelBase @Reed?

Comment: @yudayyy Are you getting a binding error (check the output window in the emulator)?  Is your list being setup properly (check in the debugger)?

Comment: @Patrick yeah i was thought that too, and try             `this.DataContext = new WeatherViewModel();` in `WeatherView.xaml.cs` (custom user control), and still no luck. How to set the DataContext?

Comment: Dear ReedCopsey, can you help me with this http://i.stack.imgur.com/tP76m.png the list have been populated and still doesnt appear on my apps. I even have added DataContext as Patrick told.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the view what viewmodel you are using. By adding

```
<UserControl
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:JendelaBogor.ViewModels">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
       <vm:WeatherViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

</UserControl>
```

all `{Binding}`'s are mapped to the class `WeatherViewModel`. By using the `ItemsSource` property on the listbox as Reed suggests you can then bind all items from a list that you expose through a property.

If the list is ever changed while running the application, consider using an `ObservableCollection` and clearing it and adding all new items when new data is received. If you do, your GUI will simply update with it.

Comment: after adding `<vm:WeatherViewModel />` in my `WeatherView.xaml`, my `MainPage.xaml`  design pane show an error `UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access.`. App run, but the `Forecasts` is not appear. In the debugger, it show binding error, but not for the `Forecasts`. The error refer to `Current` weather data-binding. I'm still looking what's wrong with my code :(

Comment: If you have any UI-related change in your code then you can wrap that code with `Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>{ }));`

Comment: Also, you can use the `DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(DependencyObject)` method to determine if a class is created by the designer, in which case you can avoid reading from files or sockets, which will cause exceptions.

Comment: any idea with the `Forecasts` data-binding? I still not able to show it on `WeatherView.xaml`. Full code can be found here: [https://github.com/yudayyy/JendelaBogor/tree/master/JendelaBogor](https://github.com/yudayyy/JendelaBogor/tree/master/JendelaBogor) Anyway, thanks for helping me this far.

Comment: Why are you not able to bind to it? Do you get an exception?

Comment: I don't know, I have follow all @Reed and what you said and still no luck. The only exception i got is `A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`. The xml file url is correct too. Before it, I already try it load the forecast directly within single page `MainPage.xaml.cs` and use `Forecasts.ItemsSource = Forecasts`, it show fine.

Comment: Can't you debug and see what happens? Does the forecast list get populated?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23264/discussion-between-yudayyy-and-patrick)